# jQuery - re-bind a previously unbound 'mouseleave' event

Tags: bind, jquery

As in the title, I'm trying to rebind the 'mouseleave' event on a DIV object,
previously unbound.

```
$(object).unbind('mouseleave');
```

works just fine.

```
$(object).bind('mouseleave');
```

doesn't.
What's the correct way to do this ?

Here I've uploaded a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sbrBS/1/)
As you can see, the .bind() handler doesn't work...

Comment: Try to use .on() and .off() methods instead.

Comment: Same thing, .off() removes the event, .on() doesn't reattach it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you must pass a handler when you bind events. You want to reattach your previously unbound `mouseleave event`, but since the handler was in an anonymous function, you have no reference to it.
The solution is to assign your handlers to variables for later use.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var handlerIn = function(){ console.log('in')},
        handlerOut = function(){ console.log('out')};

    $('.mydiv').hover(handlerIn, handlerOut);

    $('.remove').click(function(){ $('.mydiv').unbind('mouseleave', handlerOut); });
    $('.add').click(function(){ $('.mydiv').bind('mouseleave', handlerOut); });
});
```

**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbrBS/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

when you are binding the event handler, you need to pass the handler function reference also

```
$(object).bind('mouseleave', myfunction);

// a handler method
function myfunction(){
}
```

where `myfunction` is the reference to the previously registered handler method

Comment: Yep, this makes sense, but what I'm trying to do is simply to remove the 'mouseleave' event, so to prevent 'mouseleave' to be fired. And later on, when something else happens, reattach it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementById(previousRepId).onmouseleave= fun;
```

or

```
$(object).bind('mouseleave', fun);
```

where `fun` is your method to be binded.

Comment: there's no need for that extra function wrapper in your first example.  And in any event (ha) it would be `.onmouseleave` not `.mouseleave` if you use the DOM0 event properties (which you shouldn't)